# NSAsychronousFetchResult after the app is DidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a client app with coredata as its back end. Its simple enough, with two entities.

---

UPDATE: Using **CloudKit** as the sync service. I'm not really sure what is going on there. Except I can query and get results, incase things don't  *automatically* work. The problem is, as I noticed with most third-party sync-service providers. 95% of the time, they all work. Its when I test it with a more than a few devices / simultaneous calls that some undesired change comes in.

---

This question is more about iOS and coredata than the actual syncing architecture.

there are times when there is definite sync data loss. I really can't tell when and how. That im still figuring out. Sometimes initial sync takes a long time (if theres existing data) and the user might close the app, (some people double press the home button and actually close apps!). 
But no matter what I do, sometimes i miss an object, sometimes an attribute.

So I saw this `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` and I thought about giving me an option to check if all local-data (coredata) is okay, to see if theres anything missing.

Perhaps i could use a simple predicate to see of some `managedObject.title == nil` and fetch its identifier. Collect those faulty objects and request the truth server for data for these objects? Is this a good use of `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`?

**If yes,** when during the lifetime of the app would this be good? 
Im thinking maybe after `applicationDidEnterBackround` would be a good time..? Then If I do get it, will need a good way to manage `CoreData` in the background!

**If no,** well.. Really don't know wat to do then.

Im trying to actually do this, will update with my results.

---

UPDATE: Question updated to reflect the use of Cloudkit

Comment: It'll be impossible for folks to say what's going on without more information about your sync approach. If you're using a SQLite CoreData store, the store should be tolerant of the app being killed. It would rollback the unfinished transaction next time you open the store. Your claim that you're losing single attributes on objects is suspect, and points to a issue with your sync code, since normally you would update all properties of an object in a single transaction, right? When to sync is really an app-specific decision; You should consider adding more details here...

Comment: your absolutely right! I will edit this question.